# How do I create a view in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, view

How do I create a view in MySQL?

Comment: Do you have any problem with the manual? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

Comment: @@nick rulez: I always trust stackoverflow for different types of suggestions and answers. that's y i posted here.

Comment: Thanks for the compliment.  However, we'd rather you try to figure it out first.

Comment: @@mella: Thanks for your advice mella. Hereafter i will do the same and if i didn't get my exact answer i will come here... :-)

Comment: http://bindasmonkeys.com/views-mysql-create/

Comment: mellamokb its better to just get simple answers from all these stack overflow experts than hunt for answers from all over the web.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html

Example:

```
Create View `MyViewName` as 
    Select
        col1, col2, col3
    From
        myTable T
```

Answer (score 8):

```
CREATE VIEW v AS SELECT * FROM t;
```