# How to create this view using data from other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have a mysql database with the following tables.

**Excursion Table**

```
Excursion ID    |  Port ID   |    Excursion Name
```

**Bookings Table**

```
Booking ID  |  User ID  |  Excursion ID  |  Number of People  | Event Date
```

I want to be able to create a view, like the diagram below when given a certain UserID from the bookings table.

```
Booking ID   |  Excursion Name  |  Excursion  ID    |  Number of People
```

Comment: First create a working select statement then create the view https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html and if you get into trouble post what you have tried here.

Comment: Copy the table structure into the question. If you do not do that someone will vote for close your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a view in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185940/how-do-i-create-a-view-in-mysql)

Comment: @RubioRic I can create a view, making this particular one is the problem

Comment: @Victor okay, just did it

Comment: Then create the view defining in the select a join of the two tables on Excursion ID selecting the desired fields, including UserId. Once you got the view, you can query it filtering by the desired UserId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply try this:

```
CREATE VIEW Your_View_Name AS
SELECT BT.Booking_ID, ET.Excursion_Name, ET.Excursion_ID,BT.Number_of_People
FROM Excursion_Table ET
JOIN Bookings_Table BT ON ET.Excursion_ID = BT.Excursion_ID
WHERE BT.User ID = ????;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW `yourDB`.`yourViewName` AS
SELECT 
    `a`.`BookingID` AS `BookingID`,
    `b`.`ExcursionName` AS `ExcursionName`,
    `b`.`ExcursionID` AS `ExcursionID`,
    `a`.`NumberOfPeople` AS `NumberOfPeople`
FROM
    (`yourDB`.`BookingsTable` `a`
    JOIN `yourDB`.`ExcursionsTable` `b`)
WHERE
    (`a`.`UserID` = 'YourValue')
```

Hope this solves your issue.